# Slow searching and post updating in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a problem with very slow searching and post updating on my website (I have 20 000 posts). I've checked searching with Query Monitor plugin. Here is SQL Query ( https://website.com/?s=viofo ) that is super slow (19 seconds this time):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 75b_posts.ID
FROM 75b_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND (((75b_posts.post_title LIKE '%viofo%')
OR (75b_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%viofo%')
OR (75b_posts.post_content LIKE '%viofo%')))
AND 75b_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')
AND (75b_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR 75b_posts.post_author = 1
AND 75b_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY 75b_posts.post_title LIKE '%viofo%' DESC, 75b_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is the caller:

```
WP_Query->get_posts()
Main Query
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqoBo.png

Here is another query, but it's faster (1 second):

```
SELECT 75b_posts.*
FROM 75b_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND 75b_posts.ID IN (19327,13600,19324,330444,283013,330413,587881,610705,628185,628183,639260,1150866,1280541,1380663,1536242,2141749,4102953,4881216,4885577,4882266,4881347,4882005,4883739,4883740,5010699,5081700,5081697,5224840,5623788,5692541,5777727,5804331,5834759,5896805,6030583,6660368,6592214,6660365)
AND 75b_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND ((75b_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
ORDER BY 75b_posts.post_date DESC
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0Px.png

Do you have any idea what to do to improve the speed of searching and posts updating?

Comment: The second query can use indexes. The first cannot

Comment: Try to optimize your query using MySQL EXPLAIN command. Refer below articles that can help you.

[Fixing slow database queries](https://css-tricks.com/finding-and-fixing-slow-wordpress-database-queries/)
[Details about MySQL EXPLAIN](https://www.eversql.com/mysql-explain-example-explaining-mysql-explain-using-stackoverflow-data/)

Comment: I have changed database type for wp_posts table from InnoDB to MyIsam and searching is fast now. Post editing time is still slow. Do you know how I can fix this?